# Parameters inside functions in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fix a problem with two functions regarding parameters.
Specifically I have the following issue:

```
def remove_stopwords(text):
list_words=[]
stop_words = (stopwords.words('italian'))
                  
#bla bla bla
return(' '.join(t))

def clean(file):


# bla bla bla
file['C'] = file['Text'].apply(remove_stopwords())
# bla bla bla
return
```

Then when I call the function as follows:

```
clean(df)
```

it works well.
However, I would like to do something like this:

```
language='italian' 
clean(df, language)
```

where language should be a string to place here:

```
def remove_stopwords(text):

    list_words=[]
    stop_words = (stopwords.words(str(language)) # <--
...
```

The problem is that this function is inside clean() and when I try to run it I get an error about the parameter.

Can you please tell me how to write correctly parameters within the functions above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a lambda function would do what you are attempting. Something like this:

```
def remove_stopwords(text, language):
    list_words=[]
    stop_words = (stopwords.words(language))               
    return(' '.join(t))

def clean(file, language):
    file['C'] = file['Text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x, language))
    return file['C']

clean(file, 'italian')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jjordan. Your answer has been extremely useful

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameter in the function to use it inside the function,
but you have not defined the second parameter in the function definition.

try this:

```
language='italian' 
def remove_stopwords(text, language):
    list_words=[]
    stop_words = (stopwords.words(language)
    .....
```

Comment: What about clean? I get this error: `TypeError: clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'language'`

Comment: @LucaDiMauro You will need to define the second parameter in clean function definition like remove_stopwords function and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give two parameters, when you only specify there to be one. You need to do this.

```
def clean(df=None, language=None):
    # Your code
```

To be able to give two parameters, you must tell the function there will be two parameters.

Comment: I tried but I get this error: `TypeError: remove_stopwords() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'text' and 'language'`. In `stop_words = (stopwords.words('italian'))` I should have something like `stop_words = (stopwords.words(str(language))`

Comment: It seems that you are not passing in both arguments. To make it optional to pass them in do this. (I will edit the new code)